# Как распознать изображение из матрицы?

Tags: алгоритм

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Изначально была картинка, я ее по пикселям обработал и привел к матрице из 0 и 1.
Изображение четко отображается,но как распознать символ,который там изображен(матрица может быть любого размера)?
Нужно на выходе получить что это 2.
Преобразовать эту матрицу в массив, как то уменьшить и сравнить со своей картой символов?

Comment: Приведите примеры возможных изображений. Приведение к матрице осуществляется путем программирования? Если да, то конечно результат будет записываться в двумерный массив.

Comment: @Andrey добавил фото, нужно на выходе просто получить цифру 2.

Comment: Вообще это задача на распознавание образов для нейронных сетей. Почитайте информацию на эту тему.